# Random and unique Mysql select query

Tags: php, mysql, select, unique

My Mysql database is filled with about 90 image links. However the ID of each row is not really chronological. For example initially it goes from 6-20 then theres a gap where I deleted some. Then it goes from 80 - 120 then another gap ect.

It is a hot or not website. I want the user to be able to go through all 90 images without having to view the same one twice. However at the moment every so often this happens. The same image comes up twice or even three times.

Here is my select query right now:

```
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE id >= (SELECT FLOOR( MAX(id) * RAND()) FROM `content`)  ORDER BY rand() LIMIT 1");
```

Does anyone know any better solutions to this problem?

Comment: Look into a `WHERE()` clause.

Answer (score 0):

You could store the id's of the 'things' that the user has seen, and exclude them in all the next pages (either by a join or a not in). In that way you can always get a random post and not be stuck with the order that the rows have in the database (and what if the user returns later on?).

Comment: Good solution but my website doesnt let people sign up. I guess I could do it with a cookie or something

Answer (score 0):

How about getting all the indexes from the database, shuffling them, making a list and then passing them from one page to another, displaying the top one and erasing it from the list?

Comment: I think Im going to use this one. However it might be a bit slow to get all the id's and put them in an array in a session. Any better ways of doing so?

Comment: There's no way to tell mysql to remember what have you already selected. You can't do it without reading the indexes you are interested in (even if you store the info in db instead of the session, you still need to read them first) :/
If it's just 90 records, then performance shouldn't be an issue.

Answer (score 0):

The problem that you are facing is one with `rand()` itself.  Each time you call it, it produces a different order.   Random is random, so a given row could occur twice in a row.  What you are really looking for is a random permutation.

One approach is random with a seed followed by `limit` with offset:

```
select *
from table t
order by rand(<seed value here>)
limit <offset>, 1;
```

The two things you need are a seed value.  You can do this by just keeping an enumerated value for each user, or using the user id, or something that is an integer and a constant for each user.

The other thing you need is the offset.  This is important, because when you get the second item, you need to be sure that the ordering is the same as for the first item.

Another approach is to fetch all the ids in random order the first time and to stash them in the application.  You can do this using `group_concat()`:

```
select group_concat(id order by rand())
from table t;
```

Then go through this list instead of returning to the database.